# Check whether date is 12 hours before in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table (MySQL) data that stores a bunch of signup information.

What I'm trying to do it calculate whether a row's creation has been 12 hours or not.

For each row I have a cell called "**date**" which displays like this:

**July 13, 2011 19:28** or **August 7, 2011 03:33**

I'm looking for a simple if/else statement that picks up on whether "**date**" has been 12 hours since its creation or not.

Comment: Which format is it? What's the field's type?

Comment: With what datatype you store the date in your database?

Comment: It's a little bad practice I know, but the creation isn't stored in Timestamp, simply a varchar, exactly: August 7, 2011 03:33

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE `date` <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

note that naming your field 'date' is bad practice. Date is a reserved word in MySQL, and reserved words should NOT be used as field names.

Comment: ...or else you will be forced to specify the table name explicitly, i.e. `yourtable.date`

Comment: This is a beautiful query. +1

Comment: I second the advice to not use reserved words. I used accessible once and it took me hours to undo that. Granted I'm in a framework so I had to work in some rules that made it extra difficult

Comment: @Andrejs or just enclose it in backticks like Marc B has done.

Comment: It's a little bad practice I know, but the creation isn't stored in Timestamp, simply a varchar, exactly: August 7, 2011 03:33

Comment: @Alexwhin: use STR_TODATE() to convert it to a timestamp, then: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date   and SERIOUSLY consider changing the field's type to normal date/datetime instead. Storing dates as a string when you need to do calculations based on the date is going to be horribly inefficient.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using reserved words. Delimit all your field names with backticks like you should be doing anyway and there's no problem! :D

Comment: @MarcB: Your analogy is broken. "Date" describes not only a type but also a function. You have a relation (table), and one of its properties is the date relevant to each entry. It makes perfect sense for that property to be known as "date". Field names are descriptions of meaning. Your analogy is closer to saying "I have an itch on my Steven", refusing to use the word "nose" because it describes the construct of the object as well as its specific identifier w.r.t. your own body.